library inside a function
I’m developing an R package, and one of the functions in it performs a deconvolution of data. Within this function, I’m using the following line of code:
imm_epic <- immunedeconv::deconvolute(tpm_counts, method = "epic")

The problem is that, although method = "epic" should be accepted by the deconvolute function, it doesn’t work correctly unless I explicitly load the immunedeconv package with library(immunedeconv) before running the function.
I know that using library() inside a function within a package (works but) is not a good practice, and I want to avoid it.
I’ve ensured that immunedeconv is properly listed in the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files of my package, but the issue persists.
So, my question is:
What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the function to recognize method = "epic" without having to load the package with library(immunedeconv)?

What exactly does "immunedeconv is properly listed in the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files" mean? Do you list it under Imports in the DESCRIPTION and then import the deconvolute function in NAMESPACE? You could try lisiting the package in Depends (although if that's necessary, I would consider it a bug).

The immunedeconv package uses Depends: EPIC, so it looks as though one of immunedeconv or EPIC isn't written according to modern R standards.  I'd start by raising an issue with the author of immunedeconv, but they might blame it on EPIC.

I’m guessing that the import does not bring in all of the other functions needed by deconvolute.

Hello @Roland "immunedeconv is properly listed in the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files means that immunedeconv is listed on the DESCRIPTION files as Imports and also is listed on de NAMESPACE import(immunedeconv) same with EPIC (imported on NAMESPACE and on DESCRIPTION

I don’t think you should import EPIC if you are importing a package that has it in Depends (which is not good practice).
